# Visual Studio Code Intellisense does not find header under MacOS

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I recently switched to MacOS and would like to use Visual Studio Code for my C++ projects for which I use the armadillo library. The library is installed under /usr/local/include.

```
(base) x@x-MacBook-Pro include % ls -l /usr/local/include
total 72
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel  30382 Jun 16  2016 armadillo
drwxr-xr-x  596 root  wheel  19072 Apr 21 10:35 armadillo_bits
drwxr-xr-x    9 root  wheel    288 Jan 14 13:47 fuse
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    246 Jan  2 03:54 fuse.h
```

CMake is also able to find the library there and compiling works without a problem.
However in VSCode IntelliSense always shows an include error with the recommended fix to add '/usr/local/include' to the IncludePath. However doing this does not change anything and I will still be shown the errors. My c_cpp_properties.json looks like this

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${default}",
                "/usr/local/include/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "intelliSenseMode": "${default}",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

It also makes no difference whether I include the two asterisks or not.

I am using Visual Studio Code 1.56.0 installed with Homebrew under MacOs 11.3.0. The version of the C/C++ extension is 1.3.1.

Comment: Have you tried recompiling and linking the code after adding the include path?  I stopped using vscode for c++ because of the lack of feedback to the user for problems like this.  unfortunately, you are on a mac.  If you used windows, i'd recommend in a heartbeat to use Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes even after running CMake and compiling again it still does not change anything unfortunately.